# Can't clear Silverlight Charting toolkit axes by code

Tags: c#, silverlight, charts, silverlight-toolkit

I am attempting to have a Silverlight chart (windows phone 7) that a user can modify by changing some settings.

Upon clearing the charts axes and readding new axes, i end up with double axes being being reported by *chart.ActualAxes.Count*

does anyone know how to fully clear and delete all the axes on a silverlight chart and add new ones? Am i meant to call something to update the *ActualAxes* list after adding?

thanks in advance

code sample (call this twice and your chart will end up with 4 axes instead of two):

```
chart.Axes.Clear();

chart.Axes.Add(new LinearAxis()
{
    Orientation = AxisOrientation.Y,
    Location = AxisLocation.Left,
    Minimum = 0
});
chart.Axes.Add(new DateTimeAxis()
{
    Orientation = AxisOrientation.X,
    Location = AxisLocation.Bottom,
    IntervalType = DateTimeIntervalType.Days
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Chart `Axes` collection represents the persistentAxes in the chart that will be rendered even if there are no series in the chart.  The `ActualAxes` represents a combination of both the persistent Axes and those in use by the series in the chart.

When you Clear the collection and test `ActualAxes.Count` you will find it still says 2 even though `Axes` is now 0.  The `ActualAxes` (an instance of `SeriesHostAxesCollection`) will not allow the removal of an axis which is in use be an existing Series.  Hence the `ActualAxes` collection holds on to the originals.  You then add 2 others to the persistent `Axes` collection so those 2 new ones are also added to the `ActualAxes`, you end up with 4.

Run your code yet again (a third time) and you should see the `ActualAxes` count remains 4.  Thats because the 2 Axis you added in the second call are not being used by any series so they can be removed from the `ActualAxes` collection.

Comment: This is great, but how do i disconnect it from the chart so that i can replace the axes with different types? (as i'm assuming it was auto assigned at run time)

Comment: @Doug: My question to you is why are you replacing the Axes?  Why not just modify the properties of the existing Axes?

Comment: Because i am wanting to change their type by switching between CategoryAxis and DateTimeAxis

Answer (score 1):

Following code should work

```
var xAxis = chart_name.ActualAxes.OfType<LinearAxis>().FirstOrDefault(ax => ax.Orientation == AxisOrientation.X);
if (xAxis != null) 
{
   xAxis.Title = "The Title";
}
```